# Make graph of perf4j on the basis of request and maintain every day request performance

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j, perf4j

I want to make graph of perf4j on the basis of request and not on the basis of timeslice as shown when graph drawn for perf4j. How can the graph be drawn and maintained for current and past requests without using timeslice?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking at [org.perf4j.LogParser](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.perf4j/perf4j/0.9.13/org/perf4j/LogParser.java). See the code to the [GoogleChartGenerator](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.perf4j/perf4j/0.9.13/org/perf4j/chart/GoogleChartGenerator.java?av=f) and implement your own google chart graph.

You can use the [Google Chart Editor](http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/) to help you create the correct graph URL, and the great documentation at [The Google Chart API website](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/).